# how do I access the jqueryui tab index with the "load" event

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, events, tabs

So I'm using jqueryui tabs (1.10.4) with lazy loading and I know how to see the load event fire, however, each tab will have a form on it, and (I thought) I needed to bind my clickable button events on a per tab event. but I don't know how to tell which tab has been loaded.  I can tell (with the activate event) which tab is selected, but I need to know when a particular tab is loaded.

any advice is appreciated.

```
$(function() {


$("#tabs").tabs({
    load: function( event, ui ) {

//          console.log(ui.tab.id);

    },

    activate: function( event, ui ) {

        var $activeTab = $('#tabs').tabs('option', 'active');
        switch($activeTab) {
            case 0:
// **************************************************************               
// Tab #1 here 
// **************************************************************
                console.log("first tab");
                break;
            case 1:
// **************************************************************
// Tab #2 here          
// **************************************************************
                console.log("second tab");
                break;


            default:
            // No tab code
        }

    }
})

//    $("#tabs").bind("tabsload", function(e, tab) {
//        alert("The tab at index " + tab.index + " was selected");
//    });


})
```

Comment: The load event will only fire on the loading of a tab that uses AJAX to receive its content.  Are you using AJAX to load your forms on these tabs?

Comment: yes, sorry, I should have specified that.  and the load event was firing, I just didn't know how to differentiate which tab was loaded...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your load function, ui.panel is a reference to the tab that was loaded. For example:

```
$(function() {


    $("#tabs").tabs({
        load: function( event, ui ) {

            console.log(ui.panel);
            console.log(ui.panel.attr('id'));

            if(ui.panel.attr('id') == 'panel-1'){
                // bind click events on #panel-1 form
            }

        }
    });


})
```

Alternatively - you could look into using jQuery's .on() method to do your event handler bindings on page load.

Comment: This is awesome, although the result is 'ui-tabs-x' as opposed to 'panel-x'  but that works perfectly.  thanks so much!